# Jetty incorrectly reports status isRunning() and isFailed()

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I start embedded Jetty with this code:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
MBeanContainer mbContainer = new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
server.addBean(mbContainer);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext("/home/igor/projects/javalite/activeweb-simple/src/main/webapp/", "/");
server.setHandler(webapp);
server.start();

Thread.sleep(10000);

System.out.println("Failed: " + server.isFailed());
System.out.println("Running: " + server.isRunning());
System.out.println("Started: " + server.isStarted());
System.out.println("Stopped: " + server.isStopped());

server.join();
```

The Webapp I'm deploying throws an ***intentional*** `RuntimeException` during `ServletFilter.init()` method.

When I start the server, I get the following output:

```
526 [main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/home/igor/projects/javalite/activeweb-simple/src/main/webapp/},/home/igor/projects/javalite/activeweb-simple/src/main/webapp/
org.javalite.activeweb.InitException: Failed to create and init a new instance of class: app.config.AppBootstrap: class java.lang.RuntimeException:Fail!
    at app.config.AppBootstrap.init(AppBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher.initAppConfig(RequestDispatcher.java:134)
    at org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher.initApp(RequestDispatcher.java:70)
    at org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher.init(RequestDispatcher.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at app.controllers.SimpleTest.test(SimpleTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail!
    ... 42 more
543 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Failed: false
Running: true
Started: true
Stopped: false
```

From what I can see, the `server.start();` is syncronous, and my app is failing during this call.

As you can see, the app is not starting. However, the status values  "failed", "running", "started" are not correct!

My app is not operational (intentionally) and the server got an exception during start, but it is reporting that *all good*.

What I need is: start the server and then ensure that it correctly started the webapp before proceeding further.

How do I test that the server started and successfully deployed my app?

EDIT: Relevant dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.20.v20160902</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.20.v20160902</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are querying the wrong object. The server itself can host many web apps and by itself is not dependent on them. Some of those apps might be fine and some might fail on startup, so server status does not reflect the status of the web app. Server, in your case, started fine and can receive http requests.

Try querying your web app:

```
webapp.isStarted()
```

etc. It implements `AbstractLifeCycle` similarily as `Server`.

**Update:**

Since the basic statuses are not really communicative (that is, even failed app is considered `started`), perhaps using `isAvailable()` is better here. I remember using also `getUnavailableException()` to get the exact exception that was thrown during initialization.

Comment: that makes sense. Unfortunately, after I changed to: 

        System.out.println("Failed: " + webapp.isFailed());
        System.out.println("Running: " + webapp.isRunning());
        System.out.println("Started: " + webapp.isStarted());
        System.out.println("Stopped: " + webapp.isStopped());

I still get this output:

Failed: false
Running: true
Started: true
Stopped: false

Sorry for formatting, SO!

Comment: thanks for the update, this works! Jetty docs aren't that good. Both `isAvailable()` and `getUnavailableException()` do what is required.

Comment: You can also have the webapp fail with `webappcontext.setThrowUnavailableOnStartupException(true)`